# What do detached and assignCurrentContext meaning?

Tags: swift

When I add a job into the queue, DispatchWorkItemFlags gives us several options to choose

```
public func sync<T>(flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags, execute work: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T
public static let barrier: DispatchWorkItemFlags
public static let detached: DispatchWorkItemFlags
public static let assignCurrentContext: DispatchWorkItemFlags
```

I know **barrier** makes the job not being executed the same time with others, but I don't know what **detached** and **assignCurrentContext** are, and Apple don't provide any description about them, so who can tell me about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about them in the [`dispatch_block_flags_t` manual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatch_block_flags_t):

> `DISPATCH_BLOCK_ASSIGN_CURRENT`
>   Indicates that a dispatch block should
>   be assigned the execution context attributes that are current at the
>   time the block object is created. …
>
> `DISPATCH_BLOCK_BARRIER`
>   Indicates that a dispatch block should act as a
>   barrier block when submitted to a DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT queue. …
>
> `DISPATCH_BLOCK_DETACHED`
>   Indicates that a dispatch block should execute
>   disassociated from current execution context attributes such as QoS
>   class, os_activity_t, and properties of the current IPC request, if
>   any. …

I’ve only copied the first sentence from each flag’s documentation. Click the link for more details.