# Unable to understand DispatchWorkItem flags - assignCurrentContext and detached

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, dispatchworkitem

Please forgive me for asking a similar question to this - [What do detached and assignCurrentContext meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643048/what-do-detached-and-assigncurrentcontext-meaning)

I am unable to understand DispatchWorkItem flags - assignCurrentContext  and detached.
I didn't get the explanation mentioned in the apple docs either.
I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do detached and assignCurrentContext meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643048/what-do-detached-and-assigncurrentcontext-meaning)

Comment: @antoine No, this has just copied the explanation from apple docs that i am not able to understand.